# Restrict access to the authentified user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I'm creating my first application using **Laravel** and **React**.
I followed a tutorial online, and I noticed that the authentification, unlike what I was used to with only **Laravel**, is using `localStorage` instead of `Auth::user`.

With the following line I can get the informations of the authentified user :

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
```

I can access the info of the logged user like this :

```
{user.id}{user.name}{user.email}
```

Now in my application, each profile belong to a user.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/mD3yXOz.png]

Using `react` and `react-routes`, to access a profile, the user need to provide `id`of the profile in the addition of the url, like this :

```
 <Route path="/customize/:id?" component={Home} />
```

The current problem is that **any user can view any profil**. I want to limit the privilege to see/modify the profiles to ONLY those who are related to the profiles. So when the user is logged, he can only manage his own profiles, or perhaps the profiles that have the same`user_id` as his `id`.

I searched and I found that I have to use Middlewares I think to manage the access, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you should use a middleware to verify the user is authenticated.

I don't know which way you're using to authenticate a user.

Basically if you're using laravel built in authentication you should be able to use the default `auth` middleware as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#protecting-routes

Otherwise you may need to create a new middleware to handle the verification, the process of making a new middleware is described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Then you can use the `middleware` method on the routes you'd like to protect

```
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may access this route...
})->middleware('auth');
```

Another solution I would not recommend for this use is doing a simple `Auth::check()` in your controller's function

Comment: This is my login.js file in react http://collabedit.com/vfy3k . I don't think I'm using the classic laravel authentification, because when I verified displaying an element if `Auth::user` and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh I see, you can use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) to generate an access token for the authenticated user and pass it in the header of the request and use the middleware `api` on your API routes.
Another solution (dirtier but faster) would be to generate a unique token when the user login and return it in the `userData` at login, use this token when making a new request (in the header or as parameter) and make a middleware verifying the token. That way you can know which user has made the request

Comment: I didn't know about this. I might look into Passport and see if I can find something for my project. The first solution you provided seems good so I will check that. Thank you very much.